# Copper pour = Ground in layout terms?

Tags: voltage, pcb, ground, layout

Is copper pour meaning ground in the layout terms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was suggested I put my comment as an answer. So here it is:

No. Copper pour is a copper pour. As the words suggest it is an area filled with copper.

You may connect this copper to any net you like. Often GND, sometimes 0V, sometimes a voltage rail, sometimes to chassis. Depends on what you need.

Note that GND, 0V, CHASSIS are all different, and are often used as copper pours for differnt reasons.

You often also have copper pours for the power rails.

You can also use copper pours as heat-spreaders, useful for LDOs or Power FETs. I've used copper pours to suck heat out of FETs to allow for better water cooling.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that when PCBs are actually manufactured, they start fully copper plated and the waste is etched away, so "pour" might be a bit of a linguistic misnomer. The word "pour" is an industry term to describe an large swath of copper that is left on the board after etch, and usually that pour is connected to a signal.

Comment: And in general, pours are eco-friendly as less copper then has to be etched away, leading to less manufacturing waste.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can pour as much copper as you want and connect it anywhere you want or leave it unconnected.

So ground is only one of the options, but you must connect the pour where it makes most sense in an application.